# Change iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have some link in index.html:

```
<a href="message.html">Go to message page</a>
```

In other page, iframe.html I have one iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="profile.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Can it be done so that, when I click 'Go to message page' link, it redirect me to iframe.html and change iframe src to message.html?

Comment: If you can, do it at server-side

Comment: @Defense: See my answer below with a simple solution.

Comment: @Alexander and Defense: What about the solution as mentioned below in my answer?

Comment: @A.K, sorry man but people think JS is generally available when the truth is the opposite, that's why this should be done at server-side or in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple Solution:**

your link in `index.html` should look like this:

```
<a href="iframe.html?message.html">Go to message page</a>
```

In `iframe.html` do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var QueryStr = url.split('?')[1];    
    $('#iframe').attr('src', QueryStr);
});
```

Hope this will be your answer. Thanks!

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/n7wNj/)

**See pages:**

- Profile Page: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/8NfMy/
- Message Page: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/V3Qjp/
- Iframe page: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/YdXKK/
- Main (index) Page: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/n7wNj/

Answer (score 1):

send your target page in query string like this

```
  $('a[href="message.html"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        window.location = 'iframe.html?src="message.html"';
  })
```

on iframe.html do this

```
$(function () {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', getParameterByName('src'));
});

function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you have an iframe with id = iframeid, then

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").src = "new/address/here";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do redirection in your client-side..

In your `message.html` file, put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location = "iframe.html"
</script>
```

Then add on your `iframe.html`:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").src = "message.html";
```

Haven't tested it, but the steps that you said might cause and infinite loop of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your link tag like this

```
<a href="iframe.html?ifsrc=message.html">Go to message page</a>
```

and in iframe.html page onload functin write this script

```
//---------------- within head tag----------of iframe.html--------
    function GET() {
       var data = [];
        for(x = 0; x < arguments.length; ++x)
                data.push(location.href.match(new RegExp("/\?".concat(arguments[x],"=","([^\n&]*)")))[1])
                return data;
        }

        //--- on iframe.html onload function
    function iframeOnload(){

    document.getElementById("iframe").src =  GET("id")[0];

    }

//---------------- within head tag----------of iframe.html--------
```